# PHP SOAP with parameters ConnectedSoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed]

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

My friends, I would like to know what I am doing wrong in my code in which it continues giving error of deserilization. When I set all parameters correctly it shows a class error (stdClass). Here is a wsdl print in SOAP UI and PHP code. I left the comment the options I have already tried.

```
<pre>
 $soapParams = array('login' => 'master',
                  'password' => 'master',
            'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
                     'trace' => 1,
                 'exceptions' => 0 );

$client = new SoapClient("http://189.60.63.128:8061/wsDataServe/MEX?wsdl",$soapParams); 

//$result = $client->__soapCall("ReadView",$params);
//$result = $client->__soapCall("ReadView",array('DataServerName' => 'EduAlunoData', 'Filtro'=>'?', 'Contexto'=>'?'));
//$result=$client->__call("ReadView", ['ReadView' => ['DataServerName' => 'EduAlunoData', 'Filtro' => '1=1','Contexto'=>'?']]);

$result=$client->__soapCall("ReadView", ['DataServerName' => "EduAlunoData", 'Filtro' => '1=1','Contexto'=>'?']);
print $result;
</pre>
```

[Image of the WSDL from SOAP UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icY0D.jpg)

Comment: This is error: ConnectedSoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed] The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'ReadView'. End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 151. in C:\xampp\htdocs\soap\soap.php:79 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\soap\soap.php(79): SoapClient->__soapCall('ReadView', Array) #1 {main}

Comment: This is correct code: $result = $client->ReadView($params);
I used var_dump($client->__getTypes()); for to know the structure 

"struct ReadView { string DataServerName; string Filtro; string Contexto; }"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Problem:

```
<?php

$soapParams = array('login' => 'master',
'password' => 'master',
'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
'trace' => 1,
'exceptions' => 0
);

$params = array();
$client = new SoapClient("http://200.30.20.120:8051/wsDataServer/MEX?wsdl", $soapParams); 
echo "Connected"; 

$params = array('DataServerName' => 'EduAlunoData', 'Filtro'=>'1=1', 'Contexto'=>'?');
var_dump($params);

$result = $client->ReadView($params);
echo "Response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "<br><br>";

//echo "<br>";
//echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "<br><br>";
//echo "REQUEST HEADERS:\n" . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . "<br><br>";
//echo "RESPONSE HEADERS:\n" . $client->__getLastResponseHeaders() . "<br><br>";
//var_dump($client->__getTypes());
//var_dump($client->__getFunctions());


//print $result;


?>
```